Bitrix не работает оповещения журнала событий
Пытаюсь настроить оповещения журнала событий, для дальнейшей отправке на почту, в документации официальной вообще ничего нет, нужного.
Проблема заключается в том что что сами оповещения просто не работают, на почту не отправляются и не срабатывают в самой админке и что делать не понятно.
Сама почта на сайте работает без проблем.
Также непонятно почему то обязательно ставится в поле пользователь число 0, даже если стереть то всё равно его оставляет
Пробовал сам повторить вторжения PHP в журнал событий они записались, а вот в журнале оповещений ничего не сработало.
Пример настроек для оповещений PHP

Примеры вторжений PHP

В итоге не знаю что делать нигде никаких ошибок нету и ничего не работает, прошу помочь хоть какой то информацией.

А получатель указан в действиях для для оповещения?

@ВикторКарев да указана почта, пробовал разные почтовые домены результата ноль

В таблицу b_event письмо падает? В SUCCESS_EXEC какое значение?

Кстати, дата последней проверки пустая. Возможно, какой-то нужный агент отключён.
